# how can I identify sidebar blocks in my theme

Tags: theming

I am working on a theme that I inherited and somehow the sidebar blocks are only coming out on the front page although I have set them up to come out in all of the pages in the block setup.
The programmer has made many template pages which is where I believe he has blocked the sidebar block from coming out but I am not sure where that code is.
Where can I find the code that would disable a sidebar block from coming out.
If I switch templates I can make the blocks come out but I need to do it with the current template.

Comment: You can try to use `print render($regions['sidebaer_fisrt']);` in template to see.

Comment: Is this about Drupal 5, or rather any release above that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check (**page.html.twig** D8) or (**page.tpl.php** D7) and check (**themename.theme** D8) and (**template.tpl.php** D7)

Worst case scenario, backup first, then start deleting template files one by one and flushing the cache and checking, until you see the one that affects it.